# Meteor Getting incorrect typeof value on number

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a form where a user can make changes to a record. When the form is submitted I then compare previous values to new values and record any changes made in a change Log collection.

I know that pulling the value of an amount field needs to be converted to a number before I check if it has changed. My problem is that after conversion my template helper still see's it as a string.

Here's the code;

```
var trxColl = trx.findOne(Session.get('trx_DB_currentID')); // Contains _id of the trx records on the screen
var formColl = theTemplate.findAll('.trx_edit');
formColl.forEach( function(item) {
    docName = "trxColl." + item.name;  // All the input names are the same as the DB field names                
    var value = item.value;
    if (item.name === "trx_amount")
    {
        value = parseFloat(value).toFixed(2);
    }
    if (value !== eval(docName))
    {
        console.log(value+ " has type : " + typeof value + " AND " + typeof eval(docName) + " has type : " + eval(docName));
    }
});

Input field is-
Amount: <input type="text" name="trx_amount" value="{{trx_amount}}" id="trx_amount" class="trx_edit">
```

This is what I get in my console;

```
568.00 has type : string AND 568 has type : number
```

Also when I update the datebase like this -

```
trx.update({'_id': 'roJ4w9jg6htSF8vfj' }, {$set: {'trx_amount': 568.00}})
```

It always shows back up as 568.

Comment: So which `item.name` and `item.value` is this happening on?

Comment: [*toFixed*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.7.4.5) returns a String, it seems that `eval(docName)` is a Number, so they will never be equal using a strict equality comparison. Either use an abstract comparison (say `!=` rather than `!==`) or convert both to the same Type. You still seem to have `typeof eval(docName) + " has type : " + eval(docName)` in the wrong order.

Comment: Rob, geez I feel like such a pinhead! I was getting confused with going back and forth between string and number. I was also thinking that !=== was for strict and not !==. Works correctly now. Thanks.